# Conditional compilation

Tags: c++, makefile

How do I add conditional compilation to my makefile: say if I have a `#ifdef SAVE_DATA` in a cpp (.cc) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually something like
CXXFLAGS+=-DSAVE_DATA

Answer (score 3):

For `gcc` et al, you can use the `-Dfoo` flag to define `foo`:

g++ -DSAVE_DATA=1 -c foo.cpp

Comment: Note that modifying CXXFLAGS is how you pass options to the C++ compiler in make.

Comment: Yes that is one of many possibilities, but you can also use it implicitly as argument to the command ultimately using as I did here.

Comment: I tend to do both: if I define a custom rule for particular cpp files, I write it as `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -special -flags -c -o $@ $<`. Or sometimes with the special flags before CXXFLAGS, it's kind of the same issue as !important in CSS.

Comment: Of course you can use target-specific variables, but in my experience they cause more confusion than they save. Maybe I should have stuck with them longer.